# Independent CSS for Fancybox

Tags: css, fancybox

I have a page from which I call fancybox which contains some html template (something like an email template). The problem is that all CSS from the main page affects the content in the fancybox and vice versa. What I would like is to isolate them somehow, so that their CSSs don't affect each other.

Example: I have background image set for h3 for the main page. Also, in fancybox I have h3 element which has no CSS assigned to it, but it pulls the style from the main page and gets the same background image (which shouldn't happen).

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Do you have an example? Could you possibly split your CSS up so that the html being used on the fancy box was only pulled into that HTML file while the CSS for the main page was only pulled into the containing file?

Comment: The thing is that for the main page I pull the CSS from a file which contains styles for the whole site.
On the other hand, whole fancybox (html plus CSS) content is pulled from the database. 
I guess that makes the situation difficult...

Comment: Doesnt using the IFrame option eliminate this issue?

Comment: Yep, and that's exactly what I am trying to do now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have 3 options really.**

1. Run the fancybox content in iframe mode which means the content will have to be on it's own page without the main stylesheet. You can do any styling you like here or none at all.
2. Reset styles in the fancybox content, though this may be quite tedious depending on the number of elements affected.
3. Place the fancybox content outside the main #wrapper div of your page, and make all page styles inherit from #wrapper. i.e. instead of `h3 {...}` use `#wrapper h3 {...}`

Comment: Iframe seems to be the most plausible solution, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It did the trick :) It didn't take me too much time to modify the code (just added "iframe" class to the fancybox link), so now I get the effect I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: now I can't get the right dimensions of the Fancybox so that the content fits it. The size of Fancybox is stuck to around 500px (while the content is bigger) and autoscale is not helping here... :(

Comment: P. S. I think it has to do something with the fact that when Fancybox checks the size of the content, the iframe has still not loaded and therefore Fancybox cannot adjust its size.

Comment: Fancybox can not tell the size of items in a iframe. The autosize is for ajax requests. You need to specify the size of the iframe in the fancy box settings. You can specify both the width and the height Here is the documentation: http://fancybox.net/api contains

Answer (score 3):

You could split your CSS into multiple files, only pulling in what you need to for each html. If you aren't able to do that you can give the body a specific `#id` for your template that gets loaded into the fancybox.

```
<body id="fancy_content">
```

and then adapt your styles for that template

```
body#fancy_content h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

You may still end up with a bit of style clash if you leave it in one file but this will give you a method to go on to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

try adding IDs to your html elements then use CSS IDs

```
 h3#idname { color: #FF0000; }
```

Comment: That would be an ad-hoc solution only for h3, but these templates could have any other tag which may be affected by the CSS from the main page... :/